# RoS and OSX issues: No handlers could be found for logger "roslaunch"

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm new to RoS, I'm installing it on my OSX machine (following http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) and I have been having various issues during the setup, however I managed to make it compile successfully. However, now when I try to run the core it's giving me the following error:

```
Cesare:~ cesare$ roscore 
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
No handlers could be found for logger "roslaunch"
```

Here is my Env

```
Cesare:~ cesare$ env | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

Do you have any clue about what have I done wrong ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210247/ros-and-osx-issues:-no-handlers-could-be-found-for-logger-%22roslaunch%22/) by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The key error here is `command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1]`

What are the results if you run `rosversion roslaunch` ?

I most commonly see this error when users haven't sourced the setup.bash for their ROS installation.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on 2015-06-01**:
I've added `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` into my .bashrc, any other check I can run ? I added my env to the answer

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-06-01**:
What are the results if you run `rosversion roslaunch` ?

**Comment by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on 2015-06-01**:
Something is wrongs, where is supposed to be located ?

```
rosversion roslaunch Cannot locate [roslaunch]
```

**Comment by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on 2015-06-01**:
Found it! I was missing to source the the catkin WS in my home `source ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash` thank you very much for guiding me :)